# What to capitalize if the title is a question

Tags: capitalization

If the title itself is a question, should the rules of capitalization follow those used for a sentence structure, or those for titles? Such as here, for the title of a presentation on learning to ski: "Do you want to learn to ski?" versus "Do You Want to Learn to Ski?"

Comment: Note that titles and headings do not have to use "title case". It's not incorrect in general to use "[sentence case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Headings_and_publication_titles)" instead. It depends on what style guidelines you are following (or if you're not following any particular set of style guidelines, you can choose based on your personal preference).

Answer (score 1):

Capitalization rules for titles of publications or presentations do not vary with end punctuation, according to *Warriner's English Grammar and Composition*.

**"Do You Want to Learn to Ski?**" is correct, as is **"You'd Love to Ride a Pogo Stick!"**

Comment: What about "reports" and "listings" which are also sub-titled. I am in preparation for b2 examen. The preparation examples say: TITLE OF LIST and for the sub-headings "First  Heading" "Second Heading". That seems to be the same rules as for puplications. Would you agree ?

Comment: Depends on individual style guidelines. I’ve seen academic conference paper guidelines which recommend no capitalisation of sub-headings (other than the first letter).

Comment: When in Rome, shoot Roman candles.  The publisher is (approximately) God.